# angular fullcalendar loading time

Tags: mysql, angularjs, fullcalendar

I'm currently using "FullCalendar" for angular JS. Although it works fine, it takes around 15 seconds to load the calendar even though the data it coming from the php file instantly, does anyone have experience with fullcalendar and could help me optimize my script or see where I may be going wrong? Here is my calendar function :

```
$scope.refreshCal = function() {

  $scope.colors = [];
  var getAppointmentsurl = './dbscripts/getAppointments.php';



  $http({ method: 'GET', url: getAppointmentsurl }).success(function(data) {
    $scope.apnts = data;


    angular.forEach(data, function(item, key) {
      if ($scope.inArray(item.username)) {

        $scope.colors.push(item.colorcode);

        $scope.consultantsApps = data;

        var appdate = new Date(moment(item.Appointment).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
        var appdatee = moment(item.Appointment, "YYYY-MM-DD");

        var newtime = moment(item.txtTime).format("hh:mm a");

        var time = newtime;
        var hours = Number(time.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
        var minutes = Number(time.match(/:(\d+)/)[1]);
        var AMPM = time.match(/\s(.*)$/)[1];
        if (AMPM == "pm" && hours < 12) hours = hours + 12;
        if (AMPM == "am" && hours == 12) hours = hours - 12;
        var sHours = hours.toString();
        var sMinutes = minutes.toString();
        if (hours < 10) sHours = "0" + sHours;
        if (minutes < 10) sMinutes = "0" + sMinutes;


        var y = appdatee.get("year");
        var m = appdatee.get("month");
        var d = appdatee.get("date");
        var h = sHours;
        var min = sMinutes;

        var info = item.Company + ", " + item.Town + ", " + item.PostCode;

        //  var event= {title: item.Ref,color:item.colorcode,start: new Date(apnt.get("year"), apnt.get("month"), apnt.get("date"), t.get('hour'), t.get('minute')),end: new Date(apnt.get("year"), apnt.get("month"), apnt.get("date"), t.get('hour') + 1, t.get('minute')),allDay: false}
        var event = {
          ref: item.Ref, 
          cons: item.username, 
          title: (info), 
          color: item.colorcode, 
          start: new Date(y, m, d, h, min), 
          end: new Date(y, m, d, h, min), 
          allDay: false
        };
        $scope.events.push(event);

      }
      $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];

    })


  });
};
```

Most of it is just formatting dates and times but other than that it's just looping through the list of appointments, adding them to $scope.events and pushing it to the calendar.

Thanks for your help!